# ASP.net Razor MVC get URL and place it within javascript tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hey all I have the following code within my Razor cshtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @{<text>var ajaxDirPath = </text>Url.Content("~/") + ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + <text>';</text>}
</script>
```

Currently I have an error on the **..("~/")** [image]**ViewContex...** of the code saying:

> Invalid expression term 'if'
>
> ; expected

I've tried a veriaty of things but nothing seems to be working. What is the proper way of formatting this so it comes out like this:

```
var ajaxDirPath = '/baseName/viewName/';
```

Comment: Why not just `var ajaxDirPath = '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because I want it universal so that I don't have to change it for each of my ajax call depending on what controller and view its in.

Comment: Do you mean you want the current controller and/or action name? If so you can use an empty string in place of the actual names

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please post an answer to show that.

Comment: Its not clear from your question what you want to generate - was the assumption in my previous comment correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @{<text>var ajaxDirPath = '@Url.Content("~/")@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()/';</text>}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a cleaner way to do what you have described above in your answer.

Add this code to your view

```
@{
    var path = $"/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]}/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]}";
}
```

Then in your script section of your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxdirpath = '@path';
</script>
```

This gives you the /"controller"/"action" that you were looking for, and doesnt make a mess of your javascript. You can move that section of razor syntax up above along with any other variable declarations that you have that way it all stays together.